# How to assign variables to a Powershell script from a file?

Tags: windows, powershell, vsphere, vcenter

I am trying to deploy 20 vms in vcenter using vsphere powerCLI, instead of prompting for vmname/hostname again and again or passing params for 20 times I am looking for passing the 20 vm names from a file.

Comment: `Get-Content`, `Import-Csv`? There are plenty of ways to read in from a text file. These are basic commands so it's hard to say more than that without understanding where you might have trouble integrating them.

Comment: using Get-Content i can read the line in a CSV file, but i want to use each line as a input/variable

Comment: Create a loop based on the file content. `Get-Content | ForEach-Object { New-VM $_ }`, or take it a step further and make `New-VM` accept pipeline input. However, you've no code example which makes it very hard to provide specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a quick one-liner, create a csv file with the headings and values you want to use like so:

```
VMName,Hostname
VM001,Server01
VM002,Server02
VM003,Server03
```

Then use Import-CSV and Foreach to loop through the file and run your command (New-VM used as an example) with the fields from each row.

```
Import-Csv C:\folder\file.csv | Foreach { New-VM -VMName $_.VMName -Hostname $_.Hostname }
```

Comment: Thank you guys.. am new to powershell and above comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$1 = Get-content PATH

$1[ROWNUMBER]
```

That would be how to import the file, and then select a row number in it.

Seeing you wanted to use each line you could do something like this:

```
    $1 = Get-content PATH
Foreach($Row in $1){

New-VM $row
}
```